# Getting package name from PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast

Tags: android

I have a broadcast that listens for PACKAGE_REMOVED. From the documentation, I know that Intent.getData() should return the Uri of the removed package. But how do I get the package as a string ?

Intent.getData().toString() returns "package:". I know I could parse it but that seems very hacky.

(And no methods in documentation give me any clue. Moreover Android Studio debugger never stops on a breakpoint in the receiver.)

Comment: `Intent.getData().toString() returns "package:". I know I could parse it` ??? There is not much to parse as it looks now.

Comment: `But how do I get the package as a string ?` How would you like to get it? Why not posting an example?

Comment: @greenapps I want to remove package:. Obviously, I know I could do, e.g., substring, RE but that sounds like I'd reimplement Android code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the package name using `getSchemeSpecificPart()`

```
String packageName = Intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
```